# Why my css class never executed?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when I click a button, the sidebar div will move to the left. So my plan: I added a button, create a var to control the #sidebar and #wrapper div, added a toggleClass, and the class will move the #sidebar div to a negative value (and hence moving it out of the page).

Here's the js:

```
(function () {
    var $sidebarAndWrapper = $("#sidebar,#wrapper");
    $("#sidebarToggle").on("click", function () {
        $sidebarAndWrapper.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");
        if ($sidebarAndWrapper.hasClass("hide-sidebar")) {
            $(this).text("Show Sidebar");
        } else {
            $(this).text("Hide Sidebar");
        }
    });

})();
```

Here's the css:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea {
    width: 175px;
}

#main {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.headshot {
    max-width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 3px;
}

.menu {
    font-size:12px;
}

    .menu li {
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    .menu li.active {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

#sidebar {
    background: #2A2C34;
    color: #eee;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

    #sidebar.hide-sidebar {
        left: -250px;
        background-color: #a3bfff;
    }

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 0 0 250px;
}

    #wrapper.hide-sidebar {
        margin-left: 250px;
    }
```

And here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>The World</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css"/>
</head>

<body style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px">

  <div id="sidebar">
    <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="Random guy" class="headshot"/>
    <span id="username">Random Name</span>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
      <div>
        <button id="sidebarToggle">Hide Sidebar</button>
      </div>
      <h2>The World - from .NET Core 2.0</h2>

      <form>
        <div>
          <label>Date</label>
          <input />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Location</label>
          <input />
        </div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Add" /></div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      &copy; 2017 Farid Ahamat
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, why isn't the sidebar div moves to the left, or has its background color changed when the button is clicked? I can see the texts changed whenever I clicked on the button though.

Note: I'm doing this by following a Pluralsight course, so if possible try to stick to how it's done here (there might be a better but totally **different** way).

Comment: try background-color instead of background and put your script in document.ready

Comment: Please attach html as well

Comment: Whats the position of the parent element of #sidebar and #wrapper?

Comment: @HenrikClausen Added the css. So body (the parent element) has nothing set. So does this affect the positioning?

Comment: @VXp no difference...

Comment: Added the whole things now.

Answer (score 1):

I just comment css `position: fixed;` and its working

```js
var $sidebarAndWrapper = $("#sidebar,#wrapper");
//console.log($sidebarAndWrapper);
$("#sidebarToggle").on("click", function () {
    $sidebarAndWrapper.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");
    if ($sidebarAndWrapper.hasClass("hide-sidebar")) {
        $(this).text("Show Sidebar");
    } else {
        $(this).text("Hide Sidebar");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea {
    width: 175px;
}

#main {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.headshot {
    max-width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 3px;
}

.menu {
    font-size:12px;
}

    .menu li {
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    .menu li.active {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

#wrapper.hide-sidebar {
    margin: 0 0 0 250px;
    transition:0.5s;
}

#sidebar {
    background: #2A2C34;
    color: #eee;
    /*position: relative;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float:left;
     transition:0.5s;
}

    #sidebar.hide-sidebar {
        width:0px;
        transition:0.5s;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sidebar">
    <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="Random guy" class="headshot" />
    <span id="username">Random Name</span>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="wrapper" class="hide-sidebar">
    <div id="main">
      <div>
        <button id="sidebarToggle">Hide Sidebar</button>
      </div>
      <h2>The World - from .NET Core 2.0</h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work on my PC :\ Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @Farid : Copy paste exact code you in this answer, merged your previous and current css

Comment: Still... doesnt work. But running your code in the StackOverflow seems to work. That's weird. Why don't it work on mine, even I copy-paste the whole thing. I've tested on Chrome, Opera, Edge none are working!

Comment: @Farid : May be other css is conflicting , try my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally found out why it wasn't working.

The page was loaded from cache, so I just need to disable the cache and it's now working.